# what's the best practice to control linux process from web page( Rails)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

currently I am facing to a problem that: we need to control the linux scripts running in background from web page. e.g. we could start/stop a 'script' via the button on the webpage.

also another good example is: [image: linode web console example]

I am an expert of web development, and very familiar with javascript(setTimeout to refresh the progress), ruby on rails.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure if it is particularly useful, have you tried http://godrb.com/

Comment: could someone tell me why this question should be closed? I have googled a lot but not found any good solution. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @xvidun, I found the solution: using [god](http://godrb.com).

the key process is: how to make a non-daemon process start as a daemon. "nohup ... &" doesn't work for me. so I tried god and it is great!

in my case, the process I want to run is:

```
$ cd /sg552/workspace/m-video-fetcher
$ nohup ruby script/start_fetch.rb &
```

here is how I did the job:

step1 :  create a god config file:

```
# file name: fetcher.god
RAILS_ROOT = '/sg552/workspace/m-video-fetcher'
God.watch do |w|
  w.name = 'fetcher'
  w.dir = RAILS_ROOT
  w.start = "ruby script/start_fetch.rb"
  w.log = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/fetcher_stdout.log"
  w.keepalive
end
```

step2:

$ god start -c fetcher.god

step3:

```
# in the view, give users the interface to restart this job. 
<a href='/settings/restart_fetch_for_all_plans'>restart</A>

# in the controller: 
def restart_fetch_for_all_plans
  result = `god stop fetcher && god start fetcher`
  redirect_to :back, :notice => "fetcher restarted, #{result}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is linux systems then you could use

```
system(path_to_script.sh)
```

or

```
`path_to_script.sh`
```

in your controller